# React controlled MUI form field components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I feel like I am missing the obvious but I can't seem to find another posts that addresses the issue I am having.   I am trying to allow an end user the ability to set a location for an object but either entering the information into a form or by clicking a location on a map.  I have a react page with three components.

1. A Parent container component that holds the other two components.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import ObjSetLocationForm from './ObjSetLocationForm';
import ObjSetLocationMap from './ObjSetLocationMap';

export default function LoadSetLocationSet( props ) {
    const [prevLat, setPrevLat] = useState("43.5666694");
    const [prevLng, setPrevLng] = useState("-101.0716746");
    const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState();
    const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState();

    function setCoords(coords){
        setNewLat(coords.lat);
        setNewLng(coords.lng);
    }


    return(
        <Box>
            <ObjSetLocationForm prevLat={prevLat} prevLng={prevLng} newLat={newLat} newLng={newLng} setCoordsFx={setCoords} />
            <ObjSetLocationMap prevLat={prevLat} prevLng={prevLng} newLat={newLat} newLng={newLng} setCoordsFx={setCoords} />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

2. A Map component that shows a single point on a map A and allows the end user to click on the map to set the point to a new location (lat/lng) and is a child of the Parent container.  I will not post all the code to this component because it is pretty big but the important part is that when a user clicks on the map the new lat/lng values are passed back up to the parent component by  calling the setCoords function like so.

```
        props.setCoordsFx({lat: e.lngLat.lat, lng: e.lngLat.lng});
```

I have verified that this is working correctly and is passing the values correctly.

3. A Form component that is the second child of the parent container and allows the end user to enter a Lat/Lng to change the position of the single point on the map.  This component is where I am having issues.  I have two MUI TextFields in an html form that I want to set to the lat/lng values when the user clicks on the map.  When I run through the debugger I can see the values getting passed down to this component from the parent and I can even see that the state values that control the components are getting set but the TextFields values never change.

```
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';


export default function LoadSetLocationSet( props ) {
    const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState(props.newLat);
    const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState(props.newLng);
  

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Save values to DB.
    } 

    return(
        <Box>
            <form id="SelLocationForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Box sx={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" sx={{display:'inline'}}>Current Location</Typography>
                    <Box sx={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={3}>
                            <Box>
                                <Box>
                                    <Typography>Latitude</Typography>
                                </Box>
                                <Box>
                                    <Typography>{props.prevLat}</Typography>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                            <Box>
                                <Box>
                                    <Typography>Longitude</Typography>
                                </Box>
                                <Box>
                                    <Typography>{props.prevLng}</Typography>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        </Stack>
                    </Box>
                </Box>


                <Box sx={{textAlign:'center', pt:2}}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" sx={{mb:2}}>Enter the Latitude and Longitude or click the new location on the map</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h6" sx={{display:'inline'}}>New Location</Typography>
                    <Box sx={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={3}>
                            <Box>
                                <TextField
                                    id="tbLatitude"
                                    label="Latitude"
                                    type="text"
                                    size="small"
                                    value={newLat}
                                    onChange={(e) => {setNewLat(e.target.value);}}
                                />
                            </Box>
                            <Box>
                                <TextField
                                    id="tbLongitude"
                                    label="Longitude"
                                    type="text"
                                    size="small"
                                    value={newLng}
                                    onChange={(e) => {setNewLng(e.target.value);}}
                                />
                            </Box>
                            <Box sx={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', justifyItems:'center'}}>
                                <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Set</Button>
                            </Box>
                        </Stack>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </form>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

As you can see I am attempting to use controlled TextFields.  So here are my questions/problems:

1. If setting the default value to a prop value is "anti pattern" how am I supposed to set the default value for form fields if they are a controlled form field?
2. As I stated earlier when the user clicks on a location on the map it should refresh the form child component and set the values for my controlled form fields to the values passed in but this is not working.  How can I accomplish this?

I thought I understood things as I have been doing react for a little bit now but I seem to be lost.  Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: The problem is this `const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState(props.newLat);` and the following line, you're introducing a local state in your form and use that for the text field instead of the props. The "post" explaining this can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Good link.  Thank you Chris.  It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `LoadSetLocationSet` you are passing in `newLat` and `newLng` as props. You should also pass in `setNewLat` and `setNewLng` as props.

The problem is that **you are defining `newLat` and `newLng` in two places**:

```
export default function LoadSetLocationSet( props ) {
    const [prevLat, setPrevLat] = useState("43.5666694");
    const [prevLng, setPrevLng] = useState("-101.0716746");
    const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState();
    const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState();
```

and

```
export default function LoadSetLocationSet( props ) {
    const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState(props.newLat);
    const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState(props.newLng);
```

That is going to cause issues since you really only want *one source of truth* for that data, and things get messy and confusing if you try to keep track of that state in two separate places. Instead, *only* keep track of `newLat` and `newLng` in **a single place**. In React, the flow of data goes downward from parents to children, so we often want to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Remove these lines from the child form:

```
    const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState(props.newLat);
    const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState(props.newLng);
```

Then in the parent we will pass down `setNewLat` and `setNewLng` as props to the Form:

```
            <ObjSetLocationForm prevLat={prevLat} prevLng={prevLng} newLat={newLat} newLng={newLng} setCoordsFx={setCoords} setNewLat={setNewLat} setNewLng={setNewLng} />
            <ObjSetLocationMap prevLat={prevLat} prevLng={prevLng} newLat={newLat} newLng={newLng} setCoordsFx={setCoords} />
```

Then you just have to adjust the `onChange` functions in your `TextFields` to use the `setNewLat` and `setNewLng` functions that are passed in as props. You will also need to change `value` to use the data passed from props in order to set the default/initial value of those fields:

```
                                <TextField
                                    id="tbLatitude"
                                    label="Latitude"
                                    type="text"
                                    size="small"
                                    value={props.newLat}
                                    onChange={(e) => {props.setNewLat(e.target.value);}}
                                />
                            </Box>
                            <Box>
                                <TextField
                                    id="tbLongitude"
                                    label="Longitude"
                                    type="text"
                                    size="small"
                                    value={props.newLng}
                                    onChange={(e) => {props.setNewLng(e.target.value);}}
                                />
```

The main idea is to **keep track of data in only one place**, often a parent component. Even though we store data in the parent, we can still update state from a child by passing down a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) to the child as a prop.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Your post really helped me figure things out.  What I ended up doing was just removing the Form component (#3) and putting all of that logic into the parent.  I did this because I was also writing to the DB from the form and I did not want to pass all the functions down it just seemed a little confusing when I did.  So thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: By the way the other issue is that you have to set the default state value of any TextField or it does not seem to recognize the data as being entered.

Comment: Glad that helped! Forms are a little tricky in React since the forms have their own internal data. [This page](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) might get you pointed in the right direction